Zedgraph does not show point after disposed form
I am using the ZedGraph library to display data in a DevExpress Ribbon form. I am calling the form using the ShowDialog method and disposing it after use. However, when I try to show the data again after disposing the form, it does not appear.
 GraphPane zed1Graph;
    LineItem zed1PosLineItem;
    LineItem zed1ForceLineItem;
    LineItem zed1RefLineItem;
    LineItem zed1PPLLineItem;
  
    public PointPairList zed1RefRPPL = new PointPairList();
    

    public RollingPointPairList zed1PosRPPL = new RollingPointPairList(2000);
  

    public RollingPointPairList zed1ForceRPPL = new RollingPointPairList(2000);
    

    public PointPairList zed1RefPPL = new PointPairList();
 public void zed1GraphPrepare()
    {
        zed1Graph = zgc1.GraphPane;
        zed1Graph.Title.Text = "Actuator1";
        zed1Graph.Title.FontSpec.IsBold = false;
        zed1Graph.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        zed1Graph.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
        zed1Graph.XAxis.Scale.Max = 10;
        zed1Graph.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = 1;
        zed1Graph.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1;
        zed1Graph.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
        zed1Graph.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
        zed1Graph.XAxis.MajorGrid.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        zed1Graph.Y2Axis.IsVisible = true;
        zed1Graph.XAxis.Title.Text = "Zaman";
        zed1Graph.YAxis.Title.Text = "Pos(mm)";
        zed1Graph.Y2Axis.Title.Text = "Kuvvet(N)";
        zed1Graph.Y2Axis.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        zed1PosLineItem = zed1Graph.AddCurve("Pos(mm)", zed1PosRPPL, System.Drawing.Color.Black, SymbolType.None);
        zed1ForceLineItem = zed1Graph.AddCurve("Kuvvet(N)", zed1ForceRPPL, System.Drawing.Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
        zed1ForceLineItem.IsY2Axis = true;
        zed1RefLineItem = zed1Graph.AddCurve("Ref", zed1RefRPPL, System.Drawing.Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
        zed1PPLLineItem = zed1Graph.AddCurve("Ref", zed1RefPPL, System.Drawing.Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
        zed1PPLLineItem.Label.IsVisible = false;

        zgc1.ContextMenuBuilder +=
  new ZedGraphControl.ContextMenuBuilderEventHandler(zgc1ContextMenuBuilder);

    }


I have created a different class and used PaintPointList as a static member variable to fix this issue.
 class DorkEksenGraphData
{

    public static RollingPointPairList zed1RefRPPL = new RollingPointPairList(2000);
   
          
    public static RollingPointPairList zed1PosRPPL = new RollingPointPairList(2000);
 
    public static RollingPointPairList zed1ForceRPPL = new RollingPointPairList(2000);
 
          
    public static PointPairList zed1RefPPL = new PointPairList();
 
}

